# Hibernate Storing Fields inside Classes

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, relational-database

I have two classes with two individual tables, "Employee" and "Company". I would like to keep a list of employee inside Company class. It is easy but I do not know how to represent this list in the database side.

Class 'Company':

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    private List<Employee> employeeList;

}
```

Class 'Employee':

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private Integer age;
```

Without hibernate, I would choose the design creating another table with two columns 'employeeId' and 'companyId' and try to get all employees with the 'employeeIds' matching a 'companyId'. I do not know if it is possible to do same in hibernate or not. If so how? If not, what is your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can configure Hibernate to generate a thirty table to store the association as you wish.
You can achieve this using [@JoinTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html) annotation. Following your example it will be something like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
public class Company {
...
@OneToMany// or @ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "table_name",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="employeeId", referencedColumnName="id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="companyId",  referencedColumnName="id"))
private List<Employee> employeeList;
```

Now Hibernate will create a table named *table_name* with the two columns that you want and the correspondoning foreign key constraints to the tables *employee* and *company*.
You can specify the freign keys names using the [@ForeignKey](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/4.2/html-single/Hibernate_Annotations_Reference_Guide/index.html#sect-Hibernate_Annotations_Reference_Guide-Hibernate_Annotation_Extensions-Single_Association_related_annotations) annotation too.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to implement oneToMany relationship between Company and Employees. Hibernate `@OneToMany` annotation can be used for the same .

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/) is the example which shows how to do that in Hibernate