# Using the new operator in JPQL to initialize a constructor

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

I am trying to initialize a class called ShopOrder which looks like:

```
public ShopOrder(int po_id, long po_number, Date po_due_date,
            long po_part_id, int part_quantity, int part_id, int part_number,
            String part_decription, long plasma_hrs, long gring_hours,
            long mill_hrs, long breakpress_hrs) {
```

By doing the following:

```
@Query("SELECT new ShopOrder(po.id, po.po_number, "
            + "po.due_date, po_part.id, po_part.part_quantity, "
            + "part.id, part.part_number, part.part_description "
            + "part.plasma_hrs_per_part, part.grind_hrs_per_part, "
            + "part.mill_hrs_per_part, part.brakepress_hrs_per_part) "
            + "FROM Po po LEFT JOIN po.partList po_part "
            + "LEFT JOIN po_part.part")
    List<ShopOrder> getShopOrder();
```

It get its values from Po from a List called partList located at the bottom of this code snippet:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_PO")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Po implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "po_number")
    private String po_number;

    @Column(name = "sales_order_number")
    private String sales_order_number;

    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomLocalDateSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = ISO8601LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    @Column(name = "due_date")
    private LocalDate due_date;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "total_sale", precision=10, scale=2)
    private BigDecimal total_sale;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Customer customer;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Po_part> partList;
```

However I am getting some errors that are a little confusing to me. It saying I am missing:

`Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: T_PO_T_PO_PAR`T

and

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3e5970de': Cannot resolve reference to 
bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested 
exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path 
resource: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is   
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: T_PO_T_PO_PART
```

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

I have a Po_Part table which as you can tell it is a join table of Po and Part. Po and Part have a ManyToMany relationship so I am scratching my head on what the issue is.

---------UPDATE----------

This is what I have now attempted to do but it is still now working:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_PO_PART")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Po_part implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "part_quantity")
    private Integer part_quantity;

    @ManyToOne
    private Part part;

    @ManyToOne
    private Po po;

    @OneToMany
    List<Po> poList;

    @OneToMany
    List<Part>partList;
```

Po

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_PO")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Po implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "po_number")
    private String po_number;

    @Column(name = "sales_order_number")
    private String sales_order_number;

    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomLocalDateSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = ISO8601LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    @Column(name = "due_date")
    private LocalDate due_date;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "total_sale", precision=10, scale=2)
    private BigDecimal total_sale;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Customer customer;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Po_part> partList;
```

Part

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_PART")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Part implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "part_number")
    private String part_number;

    @Column(name = "part_description")
    private String part_description;

    @Column(name = "plasma_hrs_per_part", precision=12, scale=4)
    private BigDecimal plasma_hrs_per_part;

    @Column(name = "laser_hrs_per_part", precision=12, scale=4)
    private BigDecimal laser_hrs_per_part;

    @Column(name = "grind_hrs_per_part", precision=12, scale=4)
    private BigDecimal grind_hrs_per_part;

    @Column(name = "mill_hrs_per_part", precision=12, scale=4)
    private BigDecimal mill_hrs_per_part;

    @Column(name = "brakepress_hrs_per_part", precision=12, scale=4)
    private BigDecimal brakepress_hrs_per_part;

    @Column(name = "lb_per_part", precision=12, scale=4)
    private BigDecimal lb_per_part;

    @Column(name = "inventory_count")
    private Integer inventory_count;

    @ManyToMany
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @JoinTable(name = "T_PART_MATERIAL",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="parts_id", referencedColumnName="ID"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="materials_id", referencedColumnName="ID"))
    private Set<Material> materials = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany
    private List<Po_part> partList;
```

However now I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name '(inner bean)#6216f0e8': Cannot resolve reference to 
bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested 
exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path 
resource: Missing table: T_PART_T_PO_PART
```

[image: Picture of Database Structure]

Since Po_part is the join table but I need information from Po and Part to initialize the Shop_order class like:

```
@Query("SELECT new ShopOrder(po.id, po.po_number, "
            + "po.due_date, po_part.id, po_part.part_quantity, "
            + "part.id, part.part_number, part.part_description "
            + "part.plasma_hrs_per_part, part.grind_hrs_per_part, "
            + "part.mill_hrs_per_part, part.brakepress_hrs_per_part) "
            + "FROM Po po LEFT JOIN po.partList po_part "
            + "LEFT JOIN po_part.part")
    List<ShopOrder> getShopOrder();
```

I am a little confused on how I should do this. I am still aquatinting myself with JPA and JavaEE. Putting this all together is what I am having issues with.

I also tried to map it like this:

```
@OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "T_PO_PART",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="poId", referencedColumnName="po_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="partId", referencedColumnName = "part_id"))
    List<Po> poList;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "T_PO_PART",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="partId", referencedColumnName="part_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="poId", referencedColumnName = "po_id"))
    List<Part>partList;
```

However I got the following errors:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with 
logical name: part_id in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(T_PO) and its related 
supertables and secondary tables
```

I hope this post will be very useful for whomever comes across this post...

Comment: You have the entities Po (table T_PO), Part (T_Part) and Po_part (T_Po_part), right? So by default, an association many-to-many (or one-to-many defining as joinTable) between Po and Po_part is mapped to a table T_PO_T_Po_part (which is missing).

Comment: @GuillermoFernández in the T_PO_T_Po_part table that is apparently missing, should it hold foreign keys to T_PO and T_Po_Part?

Comment: @GuillermoFernández is there away around not creating another table?

Comment: @GuillermoFernández In other words I am trying to think of a way to do a "@OneToMany" in Po and a "@OneToMany" in Part and create the relationship that way. Advice?

Comment: You can use [@JoinTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html) to force a one-to-many association to be mapped on a third table (instead of a joinColumn) and specify the third **table's name** in a many-to-many/one-to-many association (see the JoinTable and [this asnwer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687060/hibernate-storing-fields-inside-classes/30687302#30687302) for samples).

Comment: @GuillermoFernández code is updated with current issue

Comment: Jaja Drew you must focus! In the entity Po_part you set the lists _poList_ and _partList_ as @ManyToOne but these can be **ToMany** only.

Comment: @GuillermoFernández I have updated the code. Maybe this will better explain why I am confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last update clarifies a lot. Forget about the database for a moment. According to the code of the entities Po, Part and Po_part you have the following distinct associations, where * and 1 are the multiplicity of the association's origin/destination:

`Po (1)-------{partList}---->(*) Po_part`

`Po_part (1)--{poList}------>(*) Po`

`Po_part (*)--{po}---------->(1) Po`

`Po_part (1)--{part}-------->(*) Part`

`Po_part (*)--{partList}---->(1) Part`

`Part (1)-----{partList}---->(*) Po_part`

So you have total 6 different association between them.
Is this what you really want?

Based on you database model, I think that you are trying to do **bi-directional** association between the entities like this:

`Po_part (1)<------>(*) Po`

`Po_part (1)<------>(*) Part`

And this one way to achieve it (pay attention to the **[mappedBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html)** property):

Part

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_PART")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Part implements Serializable {
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy="part")
private List<Po_part> partList;
```

Po

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_PO")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Po implements Serializable {
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy="po")
private List<Po_part> partList;
```

Po_part

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_PO_PART")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Po_part implements Serializable {
...
@ManyToOne
private Part part;

@ManyToOne
private Po po;

//-- DELETE the this associations --//
//@OneToMany
//List<Po> poList;
//@OneToMany
//List<Part>partList;
```

Then if you want to map this association with a specific column name or to a third table you have to put the [@JoinColumn](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html)/[@JoinTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html) annotation over *po* and/or *part* attributes of _Po_part_ entity only (do not put this on the annotations within the `mappedBy` property).

I suggest you to read Chapter 4 of the book *Beginning Java EE 7 (Apress)* to understand the basics of Java Persistence API. Next, in Chapter 5 - Entity Relationships you will deep into associations and bi-direction

Comment: thank you very much. I am actually reading that book right now and am on CH 7. Looks like I need to go back and review. I am getting an error with my query but hopefully I will figure it out. Hope it doesn't take me another week :(